# How to add new custom fontFamily to react native from server after build a release?

Tags: react-native, fonts

I have an application that has some custom fontFamilies; Users can select them and fontFamily of text will change, now I want to change this strategy and put fonts on my server to add/remove them whenever I want.
So, I can download and save them with react-native-fs but I can't use them, how can I achieve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For android I think you can use [Typeface.createFromFile(String path)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromFile%28java.lang.String%29)